# Creating a submenu/dropdown visually above the parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, negative-number

I'm creating a menu at the bottom `posititon:absolute; bottom:0`, with submenu items that *should* appear perfectly above it's parent, in this case, all `li` should appear above the `ul` itself.

This is perfectly achieveable by having a `margin:<negative value>`, however: the pixel amount is defined by the most upper pixel of the box itself, instead of the lastest `li` item.

Therefor: If you have a dynamic submenu, like I do, with a fixed negative margin, the submenu that is placed above the main above will not correctly displayed, either way above or way above the menu itself.

I'm looking for a solution this. I'm thinking of 3 possible options, which all I don't know how to code. 

**A.** The negative margin is a value that calculates to the most bottom pixel of the box (with other words: At the bottom of the last `li` item). Just like in Photoshop, where you can focus on a angle of the box, calculating distances to that point.

**B.** Something like `li:calc(<amount of list items * -23px + 20px)` - A dynamic option. Also possible with jQuery`

**C.** A better solution thought by yourself. :)

Thanks!

P.s. A JSfiddle of what I currently have, where you see my current set up is not that great working. :)
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LuuAb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LuuAb/2/

```
var a=$('#filters').scrollTop()+$('#filters').height();
$(".option-set").css({bottom:''+a+'px'});
```

Comment: I saw your edit. Both before and after your edit, the code works. Although I had to you '785' as a value on the first code, the new piece of code is logically better and.. it just plainly works. :) I hardly got a clue what you've written, though I know jQuery.. It just works and for that I'm thankfull. So mate: Thanks!